# Get selected value from UIPickerView custom delegate & data source

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, uipickerview

So I cannot provide you with any code, but it's quite simple what I want to achieve.
I am searching for a way to get the selected value from an UIPickerView in iOS 8 (Swift)
these pickerviews have a custom delegate & data source.

So the method of didSelectRow is accessed in a custom class, not the ViewController, but I would have to be able to get the selected value and use it in the ViewController. Let's say, place it in a textbox.

I can't find a way to do this, should I try to access the delegate itself or what should I be doing?

Care to share your knowledge with the students of Application Development? :)

Comment: Does `UIPickerView.selectedRowInComponent` not do what you need?

Comment: In the simple case you might make your ViewController conform to the PickerDelegate. This way you have access to the viewController properties inside the delegate method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The UIPickerView class has a method named: `selectedRowInComponent'. This function may help you select components in a picker view. [Apple Documentation for UIPickerView class](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPickerView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIPickerView/selectedRowInComponent:) would help you with your project.

Also make sure your view controller conforms to the UIPickerViewController Delegate and Data source.